# effect of SELECT on read() in linux

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, select

I have a legacy code which is doing this:

```
select(nFD + 1, &tReadFds, NULL, NULL, &timer);
.............
if (FD_ISSET(nFD, &tReadFds)) 
        n = read(nFD,len,x);
```

is the read gonna read the whole receive buffer(nFD), assuming 'len' and 'x' are big enough.

I think SELECT here is acting as just a way of blocking till data becomes available in recv buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, `select` is a function that you can call without blocking (i.e. it returns immediately), and upon return it will tell you a list of file descriptors on which you can call `read` (or `write`) without blocking.

Such a function is crucial if you want to provide a persistent service while processing I/O with only a single thread: You cannot afford to do *nothing* while you are waiting for I/O, and so you need a deterministic method to ensure that you can do non-blocking I/O.

*Edit.* Here's an example of a typical single-threaded `select`-server, in pseudo-code:

```
while (true)
{
     select(...);
     read_available_data();
     process_data_and_do_work();  // expensive
}
```

Such a server never has to be idle, and the expensive processing function can take up almost all the available computing time (it just has to make sure to return when it needs more data). I think `select` even allows for a context switch, so this will play nice in a multi-process environment.

Comment: I thought select is a way of synchronous I/O multiplexing, and it blocks or timesout until it gets a change of status on read/write

Comment: @user1035818: You *can* call `select` with a timeout, and you can make it block, but that's unusual. The typical operation is for *everything* to be non-blocking. I'll add an example.

Comment: @user1035818: read the manual for `select`, and check out [Beej's network programming guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet is calling `select()` with a non-`NULL` timeout parameter.  The code is waiting up to some maximum amount of time for the socket to become readable.  If the timeout elapses, the socket is not readable and `FD_ISSET()` will return `false`, skipping the `read()` call.  However, if the socket becomes readable before the timeout elapses, `FD_ISSET()` will return true, and a call to `read()` is quaranteed not to block the calling thread.  It will return immediately, either returning whatever data is currently in the socket's receive buffer (up to `len` bytes max), or returning 0 if the remote party has disconnected gracefully.